# Where does it say the name of the database/file I'm in?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I recently upgraded to Access 2007 and now the file name / database name does not appear in the title bar like it used to. Is there a way I can display it or find it somewhere else easily?

When I first open the database it says: `Such and such : Database (Access 2000 file format) - Microsoft Access` but if I click on anything (such as opening a table) it goes back to just `Microsoft Access` which isn't useful information. I can't make the database name/filename show up again after that.

Comment: Not *really* programming related, but has a good answer already so ...

Comment: Eh... I wasn't quite sure where this should be asked. I figured someone around here would know. I'll have to test the solution tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to the Application title, which you can change by clicking on the on the round Office button at the upper left corner, clicking Access options at the bottom of the menu and  then clicking current database. There you can change the application title to whatever you choose.

Hope that helps,
Juan

Comment: This is one way to go about doing it but not ideal. Is there anything else?

Comment: The database window doesn't exist any longer in A2007/2010, so you have to use workarounds. If your app displays a startup form, you can display the name there. But that involves running startup code. I find this annoying, too, and am forced to go to the VBE immediate window and check `?CurrentDB.Name` to figure out exactly which database I have open.

Comment: I'm often working with 2 dbs at the same time, with similar structures and it gets very confusing without the database name in the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code, compact & repair, and back up your database before doing the following.

If you copied the database and "Saved As" but still see the prior database name on occasion as you click about, go to Visual Basic code, click Tools, click on the incorrect name from the drop-down list.  A window pops up.  On the General tab, overwrite that name with the one you want in the Project Name field.
Good Luck,
Vancer

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the mini window in main application toolbar (where you would go to expand a minimized window) will show you the file name in Windows 10